# Split every word in observable (debounce untill space?)

Tags: angular, observable, operators

This is the script that speaks while you're typing (starts when you don't type for 0,5 seconds)

```
this.queryField.valueChanges.pipe(
  debounceTime(500),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  switchMap(x=>this.translateService.translate({q: x, source: 'en', target: 'ru'}))
).subscribe(response => this.speechService.speak(response, 1, 'Google русский'));
```

How do I split it into words (or sentences) and let it speak every word only once?